# Print a binary tree in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm a newbie in OCaml and languages of ML family. I have this binary tree and I want to print each leaf. Here's my code, but apparently it doesn't work. Will you please tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks.

```
open Core.Std
open Printf

type bintree = Leaf of int
             | Node of bintree * int * bintree

let rec print_tree_infix tree = function
    Leaf n ->
    Printf.printf "%d" n
  | Node (left, n, right) ->
    Printf.printf "%d" n;
    print_tree_infix left;
    print_tree_infix right

let mytree = Node(Node(Leaf 6, 3, Leaf 9), 8, Node(Leaf 7, 9, Leaf 2))
print_tree_infix mytree
```

This is the error I received:

```
$ ocaml setup.ml -build 
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ ~/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamldep -package core -package threads -modules src/main.ml > src/main.ml.depends
File "src/main.ml", line 16, characters 0-16:
Error: Syntax error
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
E: Failure("Command ''/usr/bin/ocamlbuild' src/main.byte -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
make: *** [Makefile:7: build] Error 1
```

Comment: In the future it may help to show both your code and the error(s) you are seeing.

Comment: "apparently it doesn't work" does not really tell much. Could you tell us precisely what you expect to get and what you are getting instead with the current version of the code? Anyway, there are at least two issues: you need to either put `;;` at the end of the `let mytree` definition or start the next line with `let () =`, to clearly separate the two phrases, and what you have is a prefix traversal, not infix as the name of the function suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few tweaks to make to your code.  First, in your function definition:

```
let rec print_tree_infix tree = function
```

the `function` implicitly pattern matches against one value.  So you've defined a function which takes two arguments rather than one, with the first argument `tree` going unused inside of `print_tree_infix`.  If you change that line to

```
let rec print_tree_infix = function
```

your function will take one `bintree` value as its argument.

Second, whitespace is not significant in OCaml.  When you write

```
let mytree = Node(Node(Leaf 6, 3, Leaf 9), 8, Node(Leaf 7, 9, Leaf 2))
print_tree_infix mytree
```

OCaml parses that as if `print_tree_infix mytree` is part of the same expression you're assigning to `mytree`.  You can fix that parsing issue by adding an extra `let` like this

```
let mytree = Node(Node(Leaf 6, 3, Leaf 9), 8, Node(Leaf 7, 9, Leaf 2))
let () = print_tree_infix mytree
```

which lets OCaml know that these are two independent definitions.

With those changes your code should work as expected!

Comment: "As expected" modulo the fact that the printing is not done infix as the name suggests and that it does not simply print "each leaf" as the OP specifies it should. ;)

Comment: @gallais That's fair :-)  "As expected" perhaps should be "as written" in this case.